# On/off combination switch c++ arduino code

Tags: c++, arduino, combinations

so I am working on a new project where I have 5 on/off pilot switches and a normal button. I want to make it so a 5 diget code will be displayed on an lcd and you will need to turn ond the switches in correct order (for example 1,3,4,2,5) and after that you press the button and if it is correct something will happen but if it is wrong you will be told so by the lcd and you would need to try it again. So you turn number 1 on and it stays on until you press the button, if you turn on only 4 switches in will say wrong password. When you press the button you need to turn off all the switches before you can try again.

I was trying to make a program for that but I'we been banging my head with it for 3 days now. I am a beginer programer. I tought that someone smarter than me can probably write it in 15 minutes so I was wondering if anyone can help me.

Tnx

Comment: SO Usage note: You're better off showing the code for one of your better attempts than you are writing a story. For all anyone knows, that attempt could be really close and just need a small correction. And even if it is dead wrong, we can tell from the code, usually, where you started to get lost and attack the problem at the root. If you show nothing, we can't really do too much for you here.

Comment: Some advice: Pick one part of the problem, implement it, and test the <expletive deleted> out of it so that you know it works. For example, read one switch. You can't do jack if you can't read a switch, so make absolutely certain one switch works. Then use what you learned from one switch to get all five working. If you have a function that reads one switch, you can probably pass in the parameters for any switch. Instant win. Another trick is to prototype the logic on a PC where you've got better debugging tools.

Comment: `I thought that someone smarter than me can probably write it in 15 minutes`. This is more like an entire Saturday problem. Don't forget to debounce your switches. I've started writing about that [here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/electronics/event_and_button_debouncing.md) and [here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_ButtonReader).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't programmed arduinos for quite some time. When I did, I programmed only some very small projects using C, not C++ (which I didn't know at that time), so I am not exactly sure if there is support for the algorithms I used. If not, you will probably have to implement them for your use cases by yourself. You will have to do any hardware specific parts by your own, like configuring pins for inputs/outputs and map your variables to them and whatsoever.

I came up with a solution on my PC, in pure C++ on Windows. As input for the switches I just used the watch window in Visual Studio and overwrote the values with my running debugger. This means that I didn't have any debounce (as Gabriel Staples mentioned in your questions comments), which would be important for you to figure out. You could use some timer and ignore changes at your inputs for e.g. the next 50ms after a change (to be honest I have no idea if that is a realistic approach or duration).

I don't know how you communicate with your LCD screen either, therefore I just used `std::cout` in my code to simulate writing to it.

My code might not work in all cases or do exactly what you expected, so just use it as guidance/inspiration, but please don't fully rely on it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

constexpr int unspecifiedItem{ -1 };
constexpr std::size_t numberOfSwitches{ 5 };
constexpr std::array<int, numberOfSwitches> correctPasscodePattern{ 0, 2, 3, 1, 4 };    // 0 - 4, because of 0 indexed array DI_switches
enum class Step {
    WaitForSubmission, HandleSubmission, WaitForReset
};

// map them somehow to the hardware (DI for digital input from the hardware, either true or false)
std::array<bool, numberOfSwitches> DI_switches;
bool DI_submitPasscode;

Step step{ Step::WaitForSubmission };
std::array<bool, numberOfSwitches> previousSwichesStates{};
std::array<int, numberOfSwitches> enteredPattern{};

void setup() {
    // set wanted pins for input
    // map DI's to wanted pins

    // initialize the entered pattern to some "invalid" pattern
    std::fill(enteredPattern.begin(), enteredPattern.end(), unspecifiedItem);
}

void loop() {
    switch (step)
    {
    case Step::WaitForSubmission:
    {
        if (DI_submitPasscode) {
            step = Step::HandleSubmission;
        }

        // search for the first difference between the current DI's and the one from the previous check
        const auto mismatchResult = std::mismatch(DI_switches.begin(), DI_switches.end(), previousSwichesStates.begin(), previousSwichesStates.end());

        if (mismatchResult.first == DI_switches.end()) {
            // both arrays were the same, therefore the user didnt change any switches since the last check
            break;
        }
        // changedSwitch has the index of the first difference in the arrays
        // decide if you want to check if multiple differences occured since last check
        // (if loop() gets executed 100 times a second, you would need to change two switches in 10ms)
        const std::ptrdiff_t changedSwitch = std::distance(DI_switches.begin(), mismatchResult.first);

        // seach for the first item in enteredPattern with value -1
        auto firstUnspecifiedItem = std::find(enteredPattern.begin(), enteredPattern.end(), unspecifiedItem);
        if (firstUnspecifiedItem == enteredPattern.end()) {
            // enteredPattern is already full, maybe go to Step::HandleSubmisssion or print error
            break;
        }

        *firstUnspecifiedItem = static_cast<int>(changedSwitch);
        break;
    }
    case Step::HandleSubmission:
        // if not all switches are on, or if the switches were entered in the wrong order, 
        // the user should keep entering (but first reset all switches)
        if (!std::all_of(DI_switches.begin(), DI_switches.end(), std::identity{})
            || enteredPattern != correctPasscodePattern) {
            std::cout << "Wrong password!" << std::endl;
            step = Step::WaitForReset;
            break;
        }

        // you could have an additional step for what to do when the user enters the correct password
        std::cout << "Correct password!" << std::endl;
        break;
    case Step::WaitForReset:
        // if all switches are off again, reset the entered pattern and get input again
        if (std::none_of(DI_switches.begin(), DI_switches.end(), std::identity{})) {
            std::fill(enteredPattern.begin(), enteredPattern.end(), unspecifiedItem);
            step = Step::WaitForSubmission;
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    previousSwichesStates = DI_switches;
}

int main() {

    setup();
    while (true) {
        loop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For the future keep in mind that SO is not a free code writing service and you should post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as part of your questions so people know what you already did and where you went wrong. I primarily did this, because I just wanted to see for my self how I would implement something like this.

*I am a beginer programer.* I don't know how much you already know about C++, like the stl algorithms or pointers/iterators. Most of the terms in the code should be self explanatory and the comments should help to follow my thought process, but if you encounter things you don't understand please feel free to look them up at [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) or leave a comment.

Comment: This is pretty much what I meant with make a prototype on PC.

Comment: One thing to watch out for, though, is the Arduino Standard Library implementation doesn't support some of the stuff in this answer. When making a prototype, make it as close to the target as is reasonable. Replace the hardware accesses with simple little functions that just print out what happened or wait for a keypress. When you migrate to the actual target, you replace the guts of these functions with the proper hardware calls.